# Highcharts Legend styles no longer rendering correctly

Tags: highcharts, legend, pie-chart, legend-properties

I have had these charts built for a couple months, and just today the styles of the legend seem to have shifted about 150px to the left.  They were just right-aligned from the pie chart but now render directly over the top of the pie chart and I am unable to figure out why.  I can add inline styles to the div's I am creating with margins and padding but that doesn't justify the colored boxes on the legend that correspond with each pie slice.  My code/styles have not changed and I do believe this is a functionality issue.  Here is my code;
Any help is appreciated.

```
var options = {
        chart:{type:'pie',
            renderTo: 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Overview1_AssetCategoryChart',
              events: {
                load: function(event) {
                $('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Overview1_AssetCategoryChart .highcharts-legend-item').last().append('<br/><div style="width: 200px; margin-left: 170px; height: 2px;">_____</div><br/><div style="width:200px; height: 10px;"><span style="float:right"><b>100%</b></span> </div>');                    
                }
              },
            spacingTop: 0,
            marginTop: 0                  
            },
        credits:{enabled: false},
        colors:[
            '#5485BC', '#AA8C30', '#5C9384', '#981A37', '#FCB319',     '#86A033', '#614931', '#00526F', '#594266', '#cb6828', '#aaaaab', '#a89375'
            ],
        title:{text: null},
        tooltip:{
            enabled: true,
            animation: true,
            formatter: function(){
                return this.point.name + '<br/>' + this.y.toFixed(2) + '%';
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                animation: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                showInLegend: true,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false,                        
                    formatter: function() {
                        return this.y.toFixed(2) + '%';
                    }
                }                                   
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: true,
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            width: 200,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            borderWidth: 0,
            useHTML: true,
            itemMarginBottom: 4,
            labelFormatter: function() {
                return '<div style="width:180px; margin-left: 150px;"><span style="float:left">' + this.name + '</span><span style="float:right">' + this.y.toFixed(2) + '%</span></div>';
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Category',
                style: {
                    fontWeight: 'bold'
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            dataLabels:{

            },
            data: [
                ['Real Estate', 12.55],
                ['Large-Cap Growth', 12.34],
                ['Foreign Large-Cap Blend', 12.19],
                ['Large-Cap Value', 7.51],
                ['Emerging Markets', 6.51],
                ['Health',5.59],
                ['Cash Equivalents',5.23],
                ['Foreign Large-Cap Value',4.02],
                ['Large-Cap Blend',3.95],
                ['World Allocation',3.55],
                ['Mid-Cap Growth',3.29],
                ['Remaining', 23.30]
            ]
        }]
    }
```

Comment: Here is a Fiddle of your posted code: http://jsfiddle.net/fKJmb/
I don't see the problem you describe but I do see legend is shifted way to the right. Probably because of the "margin-left: 150px" you apply in the legend formatter. Did you add that in an attempt to correct the initial problem?

Comment: here is the updated fiddle, i did add that margin to try to correct the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/fKJmb/2/  that fiddle shows exactly what i want, except for the word wrap but that's not a big deal, the problem is in my site, the legend-item text is directly over the pie chart, but in that fiddle displays correctly, which is what lead me to posting this. thank you for the fiddle though

Comment: I got nothing. It is kind of hard to diagnose without being able to directly see the code that has the issue. If your own code and style sheet has not changed, then it is most likely the library itself. If you are linking to the latest directly from http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js, perhaps an update there broke something. You could confirm that by setting a specific version and keep backing up until you find the version that works. Good luck.